# Adding and showing posts from selected user in React using Rails

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, display

I’m a beginner in Ruby and React. I have two main questions:

- As Admin I see a site on path /users with table which displays all users info + icons like edit, delete. I want to add an icon using favicon.ico next to the user email to add new course to the user. **How to get an icon next to user email to add new course to exact user on path /users/*user_id*/new?**
- I want to be able to click the icon responsible for showing courses and it has to redirect me to page with selected user courses. **How to display exact user courses on page /users/*user_id*/courses?**

Additional problem:

- /users/*user_id* is responsible for editing user. If I add something more to this path it displays edit component and adds wanted component below it. How to prevent this?

I have frontend and backend in separate folders communicating via api written in React.

On rails side I have a SQLite database set up with tables

- Users: *email password* (associated by has_many :courses)
- Courses: *name description* and automatically added *user_id* (belongs_to :user).

I added render json include user in my courses controller.

Now the React side. The problem is I have a table to display all informations and I use Courses to display everything but I can’t access Users from that place. Maybe I need to add something more? How to access Users table via Courses in React?

I travelled the internet for few hours (maybe my ability to search is poor…) but all I could find wasn’t the answer. I’ve tried to play with props in React to be able to do something like …course.user.email etc but maybe I’m too stupid to place it in my code correctly… I tried adding Course.joins(:user) but it didn’t change anything. Maybe I’m trying to add these in wrong places all the time.

Im overwhelmed with this, maybe you know the answer for one of the questions?